# Regex get column

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

Given the following `;` delimited string:

```
a;; z
toy;d;hh 
z;
d;23
;;io;
b y;b;12

a;b;bb;;;34
```

I am looking to get the 3rd column, if it exist, of any line whose 1st colum is not `d`, `b y` or `toy`.

So the desired result would be

```
 z

io

bb
```

I Have this regex so far:

```
^(?!(d|b y|toy);([^;\r\n]*);([^;\r\n]*)).*\R
```

as shown in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oABVgA/1)

As I see it there are at least 2 issues:

the 5th line that contains `d` in the first column is matching, and it should not

the matches are not returning groupings

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you want `^(?:(?!(?:d|b y|toy);)([^\r\n;]*)(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?.*|.*)`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1vvGUx/1).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew Please take a look at this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3E5eQl/1) I added the 4th line in the string `toy` and subtituting with `$1`. Now this `toy` line is being returned, because it does not include the `;` as instructed in the regex you wrote. I tried to put the `;` outside of the negative lookahead, with no success. Any suggestion.

Comment: You may remove the `;` if you do not need to check the exact value of Col1. See https://regex101.com/r/3E5eQl/2

Comment: If that answers your question, please let me know so that I could post and explain the solution. Else, please let know if you need more assistance.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I need a bit more of help, and an explanation would be great. I now changed the regex to test for Col2 [here](https://regex101.com/r/3E5eQl/6). Following your model, I am trying to include the `;` with the group, as you wrote in the 3rd group `(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?`. So I thought for 2nd group would be something like `(?:;(?!(?:23|b))([^\r\n;]*))`, but this does not capture the first group in the 4th line in the test string `toy`. Any suggestion here.

Comment: You should have made the non-capturing group optional - `^(?:([^\r\n;]*)(?:;(?!23|b)([^\r\n;]*))?(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?.*|.*)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/3E5eQl/7). Once it works as you need I can write an explanation.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew The non-cap group wrapping the 2nd cap group, can not be optional. This is the one that tests if columns from a line, should be returned after the substitution. I came up with [this](https://regex101.com/r/3E5eQl/8) it says return cols 1, 2 and 3 from lines that do not contain `23` or `b` in col 2. The structure is `([^\r\n;]*)(?:;|$)` for groups preceding the test group, `(?!(?:23|b))([^\r\n;]*)` for the test group, `(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?` for groups following the test group. This does what I need. There may be more elegant ways. Your input and explanation is appreciated

Comment: Ok, see my variation, 245 steps vs your 307.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use

```
^(?:([^\r\n;]*)(?:;(?!(?:23|b)(?=;|$))([^\r\n;]*)(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?.*)?|.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPLGCv/4)

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:([^\r\n;]*)(?:;(?!(?:23|b)(?=;|$))([^\r\n;]*)(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?.*)?|.*)` - a non-capturing group:

  - `([^\r\n;]*)(?:;(?!(?:23|b)(?=;|$))([^\r\n;]+)(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?.*)?` -

    - `([^\r\n;]*)` - Group 1: 0+ chars other than LF, CR and `;`
    - `(?:;(?!(?:23|b)(?=;|$))([^\r\n;]+)(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?.*)?` - an optional non-capturing group:
    - `;` - a semi-colon
    - `(?!(?:23|b)(?=;|$))([^\r\n;]*)` - 0 or more chars other than CR, LF and `;` ***but not equal to*** `23` or `b`
    - `(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching `;` and then capturing into Group X 0+ chars other than LF, CR and `;`
    - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `|` - or
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I would not have come up with the optional non-capturing group starting at the test column, forward. Thanks for the input and improvement. Last thing. `(?!23|b)([^\r\n;]*)` says ... but not starting with `23` or `b`. The requirement is that it is not `23` or `b`, the whole value. Please see this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPLGCv/3), the 7th line `d;23td` should not match. Any suggestion on this one

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match your desired values in the third column:

```
^(?!d|b y|toy)(?:[^;\n]*;){2}([^;\n]+)
```

It asserts that the string does not start with `d`, `b y` or `toy`, then skips two column values and captures the third column in group 1. By adding `.*` to the end of that regex, and then an alternation `^.*$` to the regex, we can discard anything which doesn't match the first regex, by just replacing with `$1`:

```
^(?!d|b y|toy)(?:[^;\n]*;){2}([^;\n]+).*$|^.*$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VAVGEQ/2)

Comment: Thanks @Nick I mentioned the 3rd. column, as an example, but it could be any, including the 1st column and / or combinations, like `$3;$1` , no more than the 3rd column, even if they exist. I will keep working based on yours and see if I can figure it out

Comment: @fionpo I can only answer the question you have asked... this gives you exactly the desired result in your question.